# .NET Standard F# library does not store non-English characters properly

Tags: c#, f#, localization, .net-standard

I create a .NET Standard F# library with F# 4.3.4 (I also tested with 4.5) with the following code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary2

module Say =
    let a = "国".Length.ToString()
    let b = sprintf "%A" ("国".ToCharArray() |> Array.map int)
    let c = "国"
```

When referencing that library from another project (.net core or .net framework):

```
Console.WriteLine(Say.a); // F# .net standard
Console.WriteLine(Say.b);
Console.WriteLine(Say.c == "国");
```

I get the following output:

```
2
[|65533; 65533|]
False
```

The equivalent C# .NET Standard library:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static string a = "国".Length.ToString();
        public static string b = String.Join(", ", "国".ToCharArray().Select(i => ((int)i).ToString()));
        public static string c = "国";
    }
}
```

gives the expected output:

```
1 
22269
True
```

Here's a repo showing the issue: https://github.com/liboz/Kanji-Bug.

This looks likely to be a bug, but I was wondering what would be a reasonable workaround for this problem?  Specifically, I want to be able to be able to check equality for strings with something like `Say.c =　"国"` where I might be using non-English characters while using a .NET Standard library.

Comment: Hm, I tried your scenario with .NET 4.0 and 4.5 but could not reproduce the error.

Comment: This actually works in a pure F# project, however as you say, when calling the F# dotnetstandard library from the C# dotnetcore app, it gives the input you show above.

Comment: @s952163 I actually found this issue in a pure F# project. I updated my example repo with both a .netcore and .netframework F# console application.

Comment: interesting, something to do with the encoding of the string/byte maybe? I tried in FSI and it works there correctly.

Comment: @s952163 I just tried FSI and the same failure happens there when I attempted the comparisons after I referenced a compiled .NET standard dll.

Comment: yes, i meant directly in FSI it works. Something goes haywire with netstandard as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue appears to be that the first file that the dotnet cli generates in an F# library does not use Unicode for its encoding. So, when creating a .NET Standard F# library that file for me was generated with Shift-JIS encoding, likely due to region settings on my own computer. Therefore, the solution to my issue was to simply save the default `Library1.fs` file with UTF-8 encoding manually so that it would have the same encoding as all the other files.